# I can not convert String to Integer (from csv file) -Error For input string: "4"

Tags: java, string, csv

In Android studio - Java

I went different ways, but I didn't manage to turn String into Int. I have a csv file and I read its values. But I can't convert the id column to int.

```
private void getCSVData(){
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.book);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String csvLine;
            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> bookId = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String[] values = csvLine.split(",");
                bookId.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0].trim()));
                name.add(values[1]);
                type.add(values[2]);
                price.add(Integer.parseInt(values[3].trim()));
            }

            comparison(name, type, price, bookId);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I use `.getChars()` and get decimal code: 65279. It has no equivalent Ascii code. I realized that only the first character from all the data had this problem. Subsequent records have no problem

[An image of debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKY2E.jpg)

Comment: Put the `values[0].trim()` into a variable them, you can put a break point to see its value before the conversion; so you can decide if it can be converted

Comment: To read a CSV file, use a CSV parser. It'll help prevent lots of issues when e.g. names are quoted so they can contain embedded commas.

Comment: did you try to debug the code?

Comment: @Andreas What's CSV parser? Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Post a few lines from your file.

Comment: @MeisamTorabi To both find out what a CSV parser is and to find one, do a web search for [`java csv parser`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+parser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the input string has doublequotes `"` or some other such character in it. 
That must be the problem I guess.

```
values[0].trim().replace("\"", "")
```

===================EDIT==========================

From the log in the question description it seems like is not a normal double quote, I checked the chars and it seemed like it has ASCII values 8220 and 8221. So the easy way you can do is,

```
values[0].trim().replace("“", "");
values[0].trim().replace("”", "");
```

you can also do it more generically to remove all non numeric characters,

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < values[0].length(); i++) {
            char c = values[0].charAt(i);
            if(c > 47 && c < 58){
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }
```

This is just a raw solution, you can do it more elegantly though with streams, I leave that part to you if you want to do it.

Hope it helps

Comment: No, that didn't help either. thanks.   csv strings are Persian language. It may be in this case

Comment: I think its either double quotes or single quotes that's troubling you here, So you can try removing that.
You can also do a `.getChars() ` on the string and see what is the character

Comment: I use `.getChars()` and get decimal code: 65279. It has no equivalent Ascii code. I realized that only the first character from all the data had this problem. Subsequent records have no problem

Comment: I have edited my comment, do try it out. Second way should work in all cases, I can't  guarantee that with the first approach

Comment: Yes, it was. That was a great solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help,  There has been a small change in the if condition. ascii for 0 is 48 and 9 is 57 so those values also should be included. If you are using that solution please mind to change it. And thanks for accepting answer.